# Angular 5 Material HTTP Data With Pagination

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am getting data from a backend resource and creating an angular material data table. I retrieve a set of 50 rows at a time.

In the returned json object i get a link to the next 50 rows. How can i implement pagination with this method. The documentation is not very clear.

**list.component.html**

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="Identifier">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Identifier</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let job"> {{job.job_id}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="ProductName">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Product Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let job"> {{job.product_id}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>


        <ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let job"> {{job.status}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="DateTime">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date & Time</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let job"> {{job.reg_time | date:'d/MMM/y HH:mm'}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="show(row)"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>

    <mat-paginator [pageSize]="15">
    </mat-paginator>
```

**list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { JobService } from './../../core/services/job/job.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge';
import { of as observableOf } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators/startWith';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators/switchMap';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-report-list',
    templateUrl: './report-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./report-list.component.scss']
})
export class ReportListComponent implements OnInit {

    displayedColumns = ['Identifier', 'ProductName', 'Status', 'DateTime']
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

    constructor(private jobService: JobService,
        private router: Router,
        private fb: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.jobService.all().subscribe((res) => {
            this.dataSource = res.data;
            console.log(res);
        });

    }

    show(job) {
        this.router.navigate(['reports/', job.job_id]);
        console.log(job);
    }

}
```

**job.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './../api/api.service';

@Injectable()
export class JobService {

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

    all(params = null) {

        let endpoint = "<removed>/api/v1/jobs"

        return this.apiService.get(endpoint,params);

    }

}
```

Data object - next (this returns another 50 starting from 50.

```
next: "<removed>/api/v1/jobs?offset=50"
```

I need someway to pagination. I can call my service again passing in the next url to retrieve the next 50 results. I don't know how to tie this in with the mat paginator.

Comment: MatTableDataSource is more for sorting/paginating everything  client side. Have a look at this tutorial to implement your own datasource https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/

Comment: @David MatTableDataSource does have an example for dealing with http data.

Comment: That's the point of the tutorial. Did ou open the link?

Comment: @David that example also has something called pageIndex. I only have the offset value and this url. So i still have the same problem.

Comment: If you have the page index and the number of elements per page, you can find out the offset

Comment: @David i tihnk you're completely misunderstanding me. I don't have the page index. Like i said i only have the offset.

Comment: But you have a paginator, which contains the current index. Your data url will always be the same, right? Only the offset can change?

Comment: Sorry i dont understand you, im telling you i have no page index. I have a json object with the data and another key called "next" which is a url to the next 50 rows

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Mat-Paginator has a property (page) that will emit an event when the paginator changes the page size or page index. In your case, from what I understand, whenever the page index changes, you want to do another API call with a different offset to get the correct set of data.

You can replace  your current mat-paginator to look like this:

**mat-paginator**

```
<mat-paginator #paginator
               [pageIndex]=0
               [pageSize]=15
               (page)="getNext($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

The event passing into `getNext($event)` will contain a `pageSize` and `pageIndex` that you can use to calculate the offset.

In your list component, you can make a function that can take in a `pageSize` and `pageIndex`, calculate the offset, and then do an API call with the new offset.

**list.component.ts**

```
  getNext(event: PageEvent) {
    offset = event.pageSize * event.pageIndex
    // call your api function here with the offset
  }
```

Please let me know if you have anymore questions. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Answering to above answer:

when page property is passed to below template. the next button on clicking which should call getNext method is actually not calling. but able to pass parameters like pageSize and pageIndex.

```
<mat-paginator #paginator
               [pageIndex]=0
               [pageSize]=15
               (page)="getNext($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```